# Unable to remove index.php in WAMP with Codeigniter URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to remove the index.php in the URL but it doesn't work.
Here's what I did:

1. I enable the rewrite_module in my Apache then restart server
2. I edit the .htaccess in my codeigniter folder. I add this according to the example in the documentation.

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
3. Then I also remove the index.php in app/config
4. Then I create a simple controller:

   ```
   class Users extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();
       }

       public function index() {
           echo "hello world";
       }

   }
   ```

And when I access this URL:

```
http://localhost/order_menu/users
```

I got this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /order_menu/users was not found on this server.
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Are you using wamp server? And have you set up some routes in config/routes.php

Comment: I am using wamserver. In my routes I have the default of CodeIgniter

Comment: Have you enabled rewrite mod in wamp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Removing index.php in codeigniter on wamp apache server!

When your using wamp make sure you have enabled Apache Modules "rewrite_module" restart server

Second

Try this htaccess in main directory of project

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then go to application/config/config.php

> **Find** `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

And then make index.php blank

> **Replace With** `$config['index_page'] = '';`

You may need to configure your routes

CI3: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

CI2: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And some guidelines.. :)