# Reinstalled WAMP now can't open my project redirects to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, wamp

I just reinstalled wamp and tried to open my CI project. I open the default page of my project but when i click on any link it redirects to project list page of wamp. Supppose default page is login then it opens but when i click on login it redirects me to default index page of wamp i searched the stack and found that changing this from true to false might help.

> $suppress_localhost = false;

But this doesn't work for me. I think the possible reason might be my .htaccess file in Codeigniter project. This is its code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
    #  slashes.
    # If your page resides at
    #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
    # then use
    # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
    RewriteBase /crm/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
  </IfModule>
```

Please Help me solve this issue.

Comment: did you restart the wamp server after making changes ?

Comment: By default WAMP's Apache rewrite module is turned off. Have you tried turn on, and restart the service?

Comment: Supposing it's the .htaccess file as you think, is your .htaccess file being executed properly and rewriting to index.php? Try making a test file `test.php`, if you change the first instance of `index.php` in your .htaccess file, do your requests get properly rewritten to `test.php`? If not, what if you try it for the ErrorDocument test? The tests should tells us whether or not mod_rewrite.c is enabled.

Comment: Yes I did @BaDDeveloper

Comment: @DNReNTi I did not, after installation let me try

Comment: @DNReNTi your guess was correct that was the issue. Solved it Thanks

Comment: @Ultimater yeah my rewrite module was not loaded so my htacess was causing the issue Thanks

Comment: @Rajan: Im glad it helped you out. I posted my answer as an "answer", pls accept it, when you can. Thanks. ;)

Comment: This link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576206/unable-to-remove-index-php-in-wamp-with-codeigniter-url/32576432#32576432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WAMP's Apache rewrite module is turned off. Try turn it on, and restart the service. You can turn the module on in the tray menu (Apache -> Apache modules), or in the httpd.conf file uncomment this line: "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so". Hope it helps.