# How to remove index.php in url codeigniter with wampserver

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-routing, wampserver

Good day, I am a newbie programmer of codeigniter. I just getting start testing the tutorial guide of codeigniter. Making the Home.php, about.php, and insert/view data in database.

I would like to ask, how I can remove the index.php in the url? I try many approve result with the same question im just asking. making .htaccess with the sample code in tutorial, youtube tutorial, and answer in this stackoverflow. I just making the basic tutorial of codeigniter but when I delete the index.php in the URL, the page cannot found my about.php, or /news/create.

by the way Im using wamp server. Sorry if my english is too bad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to remove index.php in WAMP with Codeigniter URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576206/unable-to-remove-index-php-in-wamp-with-codeigniter-url)

Comment: what is the version of codeigniter??

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the mod rewrite module is enabled on wamp go to the

```
Apache > Apache modules
```

> Scroll down list to **rewrite module** enable it.

[image]

Restart wamp.

Then try this **.htaccess** and add it to the main directory.

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here are some more htaccess available [Click Here](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)

**Directory**

```
application

system

.htaccess

index.php
```

Then on your config.php file add base url, DO NOT LEAVE IT BLANK.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: good day sir.. if my wamp server have no rewrite module? wer do I download it?

Comment: If you download fresh one from here http://www.wampserver.com/en/ should be included when use install it was for me.