# Default Controller of codeigniter shows blank page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

here is my url structure-

> http://example.com/demo

**demo** directory contain my all codeigniter application files. I set my base path like this

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = "$root";
```

and also set **$config['index_page'] = '';** is blank. My .htaccess file contain-

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Suppose i have a controller called **Home** and contain one method called **index**. I have set it as my default controller like this on my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] ='home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

// Catch all route 

$route['home'] = 'home/index';
```

Now the problem is when i am using in my localhost(wamp) it works well. But when I uploaded it to my server and go to this url **http://example.com/demo** it shows blank page. It should show home controller. I have checked it that if problem present in Home controller. Thats why I go to this url **http://example.com/demo/home** now its working fine but problem occurred when using the base url.

Comment: What version of CI you using if your using CI 3 Make sure home controller has first letter uppercase on file name and controller `Home.php` and `class Home extends CI_Controller {}` I would not leave base_url blank.

Comment: Hmmm already checked it.

Comment: Is your wamp mod rewrite enabled? Go to Apache modules list and scroll down

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576206/unable-to-remove-index-php-in-wamp-with-codeigniter-url/32576432#32576432

Comment: I am using it on live server. localhost works fine, no problem in wamp server

Comment: Are you using Windows for your local development and your production server must me on linux  ?? Are you sure you can access other controller in the server ??

Answer (score 0):

It's not needed to enter the route for your default controller.
Just remove the line with `$route['home'] = 'home/index';`; I think it's overriding your default configuration.